# Delayed Job are getting duplicated in production rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deadlock, delayed-job

We are using delayed job to enqueue the background jobs in our rails application with (rails 5.2.5, ruby 2.6.3). We hosted application through Cloud 66 in this at the time of worker server down (delayed job process server) due to DeadLock and already queued delayed job record are getting duplicated. Based on the delayed job [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) there is no possibility for record duplication. Please share some possibilities for this type of issue.

Example,

main job with handler like, ( "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/class 'SendNotificationJob'\nmethod_name: :perform_now\nargs:\n- 11111\n ")
Duplicated jobs (around 1000 jobs) with same handler created with same time.

Delayed jobs are not get duplicated at the time of server down

Comment: Sorry, what do you think suggests that it's not possible to create duplicate jobs?

Comment: @smathy Sorry for the delay. We found the root cause it's occurred due to Cross Site Scripting